# read multiarray with find (ansible) module

Tags: ansible

I've the follow case, have some directories that receive though list, by example:

Directories:
 - /path/to/dir1
 - /path/to/dir2
 - /path/to/dir3

My objective is use find module to get the files with .sh extension of these directories and set +x permissions, when I register the find command, receive a output like this:

[see code]

As see, the files is a tupple then for join to the first index I can use this variable:

item.files.0.path

But is possible that in order to the size of directory be more big, how can I join to all index using with_items?

Thank you very much.
Best regards

```
"results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "examined": 2,
                "failed": false,
                "files": [
                    {

                        ..
                        "path": "/path/to/dir1/ficheros20.txt",
                        ..                    
                    },
                    {

                        ..
                        "path": "/path/to/dir1/ficheros20.txt",
                        ..                    
                    }
                ],
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "age": null,
                        "age_stamp": "mtime",
                        "contains": null,
                        "depth": null,
                        "excludes": null,
                        "file_type": "file",
                        "follow": false,
                        "get_checksum": false,
                        "hidden": false,
                        "path": "/path/to/dir1/",
                        "paths": [
                            "/path/to/dir1/"
                        ],
                        "patterns": [
                            "*"
                        ],
                        "recurse": false,
                        "size": null,
                        "use_regex": false
                    }
                },
                "item": "/path/to/dir1/",
                "matched": 2,
                "msg": ""
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "changed": false,
                "examined": 2,
                "failed": false,
                "files": [
                    {
                        ..
                        "path": "/path/to/dir2/ficheros20.txt",
                        ..
                    },
                    {

                        ..
                        "path": "/path/to/dir2/ficheros20.txt",
                        ..                    
                    }
                ],
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "age": null,
                        "age_stamp": "mtime",
                        "contains": null,
                        "depth": null,
                        "excludes": null,
                        "file_type": "file",
                        "follow": false,
                        "get_checksum": false,
                        "hidden": false,
                        "path": "/path/to/dir2/",
                        "paths": [
                            "/path/to/dir2/"
                        ],
                        "patterns": [
                            "*"
                        ],
                        "recurse": false,
                        "size": null,
                        "use_regex": false
                    }
                },
                "item": "/path/to/dir2/",
                "matched": 2,
                "msg": ""
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: How can I join to all index using with_items?

A: Try json_query

```
loop: "{{ results|json_query('[].files[].path')|flatten }}"
```

(not tested)